# Covering Map $S^3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$

Tags: general-topology, matrices, covering-spaces

I have a question about a stetement in wiki's article about real projective space:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space

There is said that the covering map $S3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$ is a map of groups $Spin(3) \to SO(3)$, where $Spin(3)$ is a Lie group that is the universal cover of $SO(3)$.

What does it mean? Why $S^3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$ equals $Spin(3) \to SO(3)$?

I suppose that $\mathbb{RP}^3 \cong SO(3)$ holds (by the way, do anybody know a nice argument that it's not only a bijection, but also homeomorphism?).

But does $S^3 \cong Spin(3)$ also hold?

Comment: How do you define $Spin (3)$?

Comment: As universal cover of $SO(3)$. Ah, yes , I see it, $S^3$ is also simply connected, so also a universal cover, which is unique up to isomorphism. Is it a correct argument?